# Testing a function that uses a service Jasmine spyOnObject

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I'm trying to test a function that is initiated by a button click

If the button value equals "Yes" apply a custom validator to a formGroup

The validator requires a parameter which is a service "this.stateService", which returns a number "0" for this test.

Actual function:

```
  onSelected(): void {
        const myFormGroup: AbstractControl = this.form.controls.fGroup;
            if (this.form.get('button').value === 'Yes') {
                myFormGroup.validator = myValidation.requireCheckboxesToBeChecked(this.stateService);
                } else {
                myFormGroup.setValidators(null);
                }
            myFormGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
```

In the validator file:

```
static requireCheckboxesToBeChecked(stateService: StateService): ValidatorFn {
    return function validate (formGroup: FormGroup): { [key: string]: boolean } | null  {
      const checkedCount = stateService.currentCheckedCount();
      if (checkedCount === 0) {
          return  {
            'isNotChecked' : true
          };
        }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

The test function:

```
import { myValidation } from '@app/shared/validators/modification.validator';

const mockStateService = jasmine.createSpyObj('StateService',
    [ 'getCategoryState',
      'getCheckedCount'
    ]);

  it('should add validation to my form group when value is Yes', () => {

    const vehicleModificationsFormGroup = component.form.controls['vehicleModifications'];

    component.form.get('button').setValue('Yes');
    component.onSelected();

    myFormGroup.validator = myValidation.requireCheckboxesToBeChecked(mockStateService);
    expect(mockStateService.currentCheckedCount).toEqual(0);
    expect(myFormGroup.validator.length).toBe(1);
  });
```

I'm getting "stateService.currentCheckedCount is not a function" which is in the validator file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mock you are defining (`mockStateService`) doesn't have a `currentCheckedCount` method.

The `mockStateService` does only have two methods `getCategoryState` and `getCheckedCount`.

If you want to mock just some methods of an object, you could try `spyOn` on an instance of ExampleService.

- [Link to spyOn mocking the call](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.returnValue%3C/code%3E)
- [Link to spyOn mocking a method and being able to use parameters](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callFake%3C/code%3E)
- [Link to spyOn mocking a method and calling the real one](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E)

And so on, there are another options to spy/mock some methods.

You can also try to define what you want to return using createSpyObj:

```
const mockStateService = jasmine.createSpyObj('StateService',  
    { 
       getCategoryState: function() {
          return "ifItMathersReturnSomething";
       },
       getCheckedCount: function() {
          return "anotherThing";
       },
       currentCheckedCount: function() {
          return 0;
       } 
   }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that! had to make a slight adjustment to the mockService function call, but works now

Answer (score 1):

@stp18's answer put me on the right track, the function was missing from the array

However, I did have to modify the call to the mockService to return a value, rather than be equal to

```
    import { myValidation } from '@app/shared/validators/modification.validator';

    const mockStateService = jasmine.createSpyObj('StateService',
             [ 'currentCheckedCount',
               'getCheckedCount'
             ]);

    it('should add validation to my form group when value is Yes', () => {

    const vehicleModificationsFormGroup = component.form.controls['vehicleModifications'];

    component.form.get('button').setValue('Yes');
    component.onSelected();

    myFormGroup.validator = myValidation.requireCheckboxesToBeChecked(mockStateService);
    mockStateService.currentCheckedCount.and.returnValue(0);
    expect(myFormGroup.validator.length).toBe(1);
  });
```